# Create a new property and get element id?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, prototype, element

I want to create a new property and get id for elements (demo1, demo2, demo3).

id: this.id = How do I get the id from the elements here?

```js
Element.prototype.myData = {
  id: '1', 
  name: 'Caesar',
  title: 'Imperator'
  var att = "{id:"+id+";name:"+name+";title:"+title+"}";
  document.getElementById(this.id).setAttribute("myAtt", att); // get id of element
  
};

alert(document.getElementById("demo1").myData.id = "129"); // alert 129

alert(document.getElementById("demo2").myData.id = "65"); // alert 65
alert(document.getElementById("demo2").myData.name = "Aleksandar"); // alert Aleksandar

alert(document.getElementById("demo3").myData.title); // alert Imperator
```

```html
<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
<div id="demo3"></div>
```

Comment: This seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to add an object to the prototype of all elements and reflect the `id` property on it?

Comment: Also, the way you're doing what you're doing, **all** elements will have the **same** data. That seems unlikely to be what you really want.

Comment: You can't do this simply. It can be done in a fairly complex way. I **do not** recommend it. :-) You'd have to make the `myData` property an *accessor* property that redefines itself on the element the first time it's used. I don't see any benefit to that vs. (say) a `WeakMap` that maps elements to data.

Comment: I just need an id of the elements so I can manipulate the elements and values. The code is much more complex, this is simplified just to explain the problem (get id). This would greatly simplify my previous code.

Comment: You don't need `id` values to manipulate DOM elements (but it's one way of doing it). Again, why do you need a single object on the `Element` prototype that's shared by all elements? `name` and `title` would be the same for all of them, you may as well just use constants in the code.

Comment: I've edited the code a bit, just to see why I need it. Otherwise the code is much more complex. I just need this.id ...

Comment: in my opionion, it will be better to to use CustomElements and override its logic instead of using native elements itselfs, you can use divs as you suggested below by using CustomElements basing on class extention.. take a look at [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: and here is a concrete example as you suggest [take a look Here in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4ektg3a/16/)

Comment: And this is good. Can I apply this to all elements or just to the div tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class CustomDiv extends HTMLDivElement {
    myData = {
       id: '',
       name: 'Caesar',
       title: 'Imperator'
    };
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.myData.id = this.getAttribute('id');
    }
}

customElements.define('custom-div',CustomDiv , {extends: 'div'});


alert(document.getElementById("demo1").myData.id); // alert demo1

alert(document.getElementById("demo2").myData.name); // alert Cesar

alert(document.getElementById("demo3").myData.title); // alert Imperator
```

```html
<div is="custom-div" id="demo1"></div>
<div is="custom-div" id="demo2"></div>
<div is="custom-div" id="demo3"></div>
```